# Looping object values

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have an object which I want to loop in. I'm doing the same thing what I'm doing with array but I can't seem to get it done with objects. here:

```
var friends = {};
friends.bill = {
  firstName: "Bill",
  lastName: "Gates",
  number: "(206) 555-5555",
  address: ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014']

};
friends.steve = {
  firstName: "Steve",
  lastName: "Jobs",
  number: "(408) 555-5555",
  address: ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014']

};

function search(name){
     for(x=0; x<friends.length; x++){

            if(friends[x].firstName===name){
                    console.log(friends[x]);
                    return friends[x];
                }   
         }

}    

search("Steve");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects don't have a length, so you use the `for in` syntax:

```
function search(name){
    for(var friend in friends){
        if(friends[friend].firstName===name){
            console.log(friends[friend]);
            return friends[friend];
        }   
     }
}
```

Comment: A **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/91yjyv8y/1/)** to add up with.. :)